# Localize month from variable

Tags: php, date, localization

I have a variable `$date` which will show `'2 May'` when I `var_dump` this:

```
var_dump(date('j F', $date));
```

Now I want F to show in locale language and I have found out that:

```
$monthNum = $month = $date->month;
var_dump(strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum)));
```

will show the month correctly in locale language.

Now I was wondering what is the best way to combine these two into one, so that it will show `2 Mei` (Dutch for May) instead of `2 May`. Is it possible to use `strftime()` and `mktime()` inside `date()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I didn't need to use `mktime()` at all.

`strftime('%e %B', $date)` did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
```

Before the strftime...
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: Thnx, but strftime already works, I need to combine it with/inside `date()` so I can show the day number too